# Automate burning of 100+ .ISO DVD images

Tags: windows, dvd, dvd-burning

Suppose I have a directory of 100 .ISO files.  Do you know how I could automate burning them to DVDs?  I'd basically like to send them to a DVD burner with a hopper of DVDs similar to how you can print sheets of paper on a printer.

Any ideas on how to do this on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.imgburn.com/

"There is an image queue system for when you're burning several images (which you can automatically share between multiple drives if you have more than one)"

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, write a simple bash script which uses cdrecord.

Answer (score 1):

Rimage http://www.rimage.com/products/software/rimage-system-software.html has duplication towers with software and an SDK which would provide you with the hardware and software required for writing lots of different discs in a big batch.

Comment: Thanks! That's what we ended up using in 2008 along with a few pieces of software and a custom winforms app. It worked well enough.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS, you could probably use Toast and AppleScript it.

BTW, what do you mean by "hopper"? You don't think of a mechanism to swap the media for you, do you? There are such machines, but that's not really programming related, and they come with software for such a task.

Comment: I'm thinking of using a machine like this: http://www.primera.com/bravopro_disc_publisher.html but I want to find one that I can automate to burn different .ISOs.  Lots of them only support duplicating DVDs.